# Convert string of list to list type object

Tags: python, list, file-io

I have a file where data are stored like this:

```
[(4, u'name1'), (7, u'name2'), (10, u'name3'), (17, u'name4')]
```

Now if I read the file this data is read as string. I want to convert it a list of tuples as they show. like,

```
[(4, u'name1'), (7, u'name2'), (10, u'name3'), (17, u'name4')]
```

If i use `list(data)` it gives me like:

```
['[', '(', '4', ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', '1', "'", ')', ',', ' ', '(', '7', ',', ' ', 'u', "'", 'n', 'a', 'm', 'e', '2', "'", ')', ']']
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: @TanveerAlam: Yikes, no! Never use `eval()` if you can avoid it. [`eval() is evil`](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Comment: why don't use json for serializing/unserializing the list? (however json.loads(json.dumps(l)) != l as the internal tuples will be loaded as lists). However, don't use eval on an external input, it's dangerous (http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Comment: @TimPietzcker - Thanks for saving me from the evil :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest using [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). This is [preferred over `eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval).

```
>>> s = "[(4, u'name1'), (7, u'name2'), (10, u'name3'), (17, u'name4')]"
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(s)
[(4, 'name1'), (7, 'name2'), (10, 'name3'), (17, 'name4')]
```